# Stuck on importing images to collection from Lightroom mobile

Tags: lightroom, iphone, lightroom-catalog, import

I am using Lightroom CC 2015. I have synced my iPhone images using Lightroom mobile. This leads to the images being available:

- in the collection "iPhone Photos" in the box "From LR Mobile".
- in the "Imported Photos" folder under "PortMind" which is the name of my iPhone.

So far so good - the images are obviously somewhere on my mac.

I want to import these images to my normal file structure on my harddisk so that they end up alongside my other pictures. I would preferably be able to use my import settings placing them in folders named according to dates the same way my other images are stored. I know that the preferences for storing imagery can lead to long discussions. We all have our preferences and this is mine.

This will make it possible to establish a workflow from my cellphone to my image archive curated through Lightroom.

How can I do this?

I should note that I am rather new to Lightroom and Lightroom mobile.